# How many adjuncts are in the sentence?

Tags: adjuncts

In the following sentence I've identified 3 adjuncts, is it correct?

> The book with the blue cover on the shelf in the drawing room is the one that you gave me.

1. blue cover
2. on the shelf
3. in the drawing room

But I think without any one of the adjuncts the sentence is incorrect.

The book with the blue cover is the one that you gave me.

The book on the shelf is the one that you gave me.

The book in the drawing room is the one that you gave me.

Is my understanding of adjuncts correct?

Actual question in the assignment:

[image]

Comment: Nothing incorrect about any of those sentences - they just include less information.

Comment: No: There are no adjuncts here. Adjuncts are modifiers in clause structure, not phrase structure. In your example, the preposition phrase "with the blue cover" modifies "book". "On the shelf in the dining room" is a PP also modifying "book" in which the PP in the dining room" modifies "shelf". Thus the PPs are not adjuncts but modifiers in phrase structure.

Comment: @BillJ The question in the assignment specifically asks how many adjuncts are there in the sentence.

Comment: @Abbas Well, the answer is none, as I explained in my first comment. Adjuncts (also called adverbials) modify verbs and verb phrases, not nouns. They typically express the circumstances in a clause, such as manner. reason, duration, purpose, condition etc. You might want to consider getting a new grammar book.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjunct_(grammar) uses the term "adnominal adjunct". I think the term "adjunct" lacks a universally accepted definition.

Answer (score 0):

An **adjunct** adds extra information **to the phrase/clause.** For example:

> I keep a copy of that book in my desk.

"in my desk" is an adjunct

A **postmodifier** adds extra information that tells you more about the **noun**. For example:

> I really like the book with the blue cover.

"with the blue cover" is a postmodifier, not an adjunct.

So when you look at your question:

> The book with the blue cover on the shelf in the drawing room is the one that you gave me.

I think:

**Postmodifiers**: "with the blue cover", "on the shelf", "in the drawing room"

**Adjunct**: "that you gave me"

BTW, you can remove one or all of the postmodifiers and the resulting sentence is perfectly valid.

[More examples (and reference) here.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/adjuncts)

Comment: I'd go along with what you say except that the expression _that you gave me_ is a relative clause modifying "one", and thus is not an adjunct but a modifier in noun phrase structure.

Answer (score 0):

> *The book with the blue cover on the shelf in the drawing room is the*
> *one that you gave me*.

Adjuncts are modifiers in clause structure, not phrase structure. In your example, the preposition phrase "with the blue cover" modifies "book".

"On the shelf in the dining room" is a PP also modifying "book" in which the PP "in the dining room" modifies "shelf". Thus the PPs are not adjuncts but modifiers in phrase structure.

Note that adjuncts (sometimes called adverbials) modify verbs and verb phrases in clauses, not nouns, where they typically express the semantic circumstances in a clause, such as manner, time, reason, duration, purpose, condition etc.